# How to disable "Tab Tab to accept" tooltip in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

How can the following little tooltip be disabled (hidden)?

[image]

Or

[image]

I know that I can accept with "Tab Tab" or get the next suggestion with Alt+., I don't want that VS shows me that every time (because it overlaps the previous two code lines).

Notes:

- I don't want to disable the suggestion itself, I just don't want to see the tooltip.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2022, 17.4.2 (Enterprise).
- I'm using C#

Comment: You can't hide this, just can enable/disable the feature.

Comment: and how? it irritates my quite a bit when editing..

Answer (score 3):

The feature is called Intelli**Code** (don't confuse with Intellisense).
In case someone is looking for a way to disable it altogether:

- Search for it in Tools -> Options
- Disable "C# suggestions"

  [image]

If you want to still keep it but stop interfering with the tab actions you are used to, there is a way to assign "accept" to right arrow:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer using windows 11?

This tooltip is displayed on my colleague's computer:

[image]

But it doesn't show up on my computer:

[image]

The only difference is that he is using windows11 and I am using windows10.

I think it's a problem in visual studio. Maybe you can report this problem on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report).

Comment: I'm also using Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try to reset all settings in Tools > Import and Export Settings. If it does not work, I think you can report this feature on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report). It may also be a change after the vs version update.

Comment: This is not related to Windows 10 or WIndows 11. These are settings from `Tools > Options > Intellicode > General` and `Tools > Options > Intellicode > Advanced`.